# Generating a new email address on the fly, but not really!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have a blogging application. Once a blog-post is created by a user, it will be sent as an email to some of user's friends. I want a functionality where the friends will just reply to the email and the content of the email will go as comments for that particular blog-post.

One way to do this is to do something similar to what http://ohlife.com does. It basically creates a unique ID per user per day, has the reply-to attribute of the email set to `post+{unique_id}@ohlife.com` and probably parses this field to know which user is the email for, when it gets received. But it really has only 1 email address which is `post@ohlife.com`. The part after the "+" get's ignored by email servers. This also is applicable to gmail.

What I wanted to know, is whether this property is for particular email servers or is it universal? If it is not universal, is there is email server independent way of implementing this? I would not want this to be based on the email subject, as it's the trivial solution I know of.

Answer (score 1):

it is depending on your mail server and how it is configured.. (although it is quite a standard) - for example in postfix:

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

you could set it to anything you like .. i once configured it to be a dot so i can use it all over the web.. http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter

but you could simply make it configurable in your application as well..

Answer (score 1):

Besides using the email subject or address, one other easy way to accomplish this would be to just stick an identifier number at the bottom of the outgoing email's body. It would then come back to you in the quoted part of the response message. This is much less obtrusive than putting stuff in the subject or address, and if you're using HTML messages you can even make the code invisible.

Comment: That's a good approach but sometimes people do remove the quoted text before sending a reply out. I actually had thought of this initially but did not go for it because of the possibility I just mentioned. Thanks anyways.